# Bar chart axis changes as per parameter values

Tags: tableau-api

I have a report which will have a parameter (values: Daily , weekly , Monthly ) and based on the selection , bar chart below changes axis.

eg: if user selects daily then only current week data gets displayed ( 7 days) , If weekly then last 4 weeks data ( means 4 bars , one bar per week) , and if monthly then last 3 months data ( 3 bars , one per month).

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a good report to have. What is going wrong?

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you have tried so far that is not working, as well as framing a question that the community could attempt to address.